# How to create a user in OpenAM with create realm privilege?

Tags: directoryservices, openam, opensso

How can I create a user in OpenAM/OpenSSO with create realm privilege (Other than amAdmin)? We need this feature to be make our b2b users able to create sub-organizations in turn.

Comment: If you create a delegated administrator who can manage a realm (for example, `realm1`), the administrator can create realms under his realm (for example, `/realm1/realm11`). Does it satisfy your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the delegation API is available via the ClientSDK, however if memory serves older versions of the ClientSDK required additional server side libraries to be on the classpath to actually allow those APIs to work.

The essence of creating delegated admins via ClientSDK would be something like:

- create a user
- create a new group
- add the user to the group
- create a delegation privilege giving access to the group.

The Java code for the last part would be:

```
DelegationManager delegationManager = new DelegationManager(adminToken, realmName);
Set<String> groups = Collections.singleton(group.getUniversalId());
DelegationPrivilege realmAdminPrivilege = new DelegationPrivilege("RealmAdmin", groups, realmName);
delegationManager.addPrivilege(realmAdminPrivilege);
```

When using the REST APIs, I would suggest to interact with the policies instead (delegation privileges are in fact just "special" policies stored under a hidden realm under the sunAMDelegationService policy set).